# Get value of Jtextfield in another JFrame

Tags: user-interface, jframe, jtextfield

So I'm practicing a GUI in Java and did my first project by making a Registration Form. I did it well but then I want to continue it by making another JFrame that contains a Log in Form. But I'm having a problem in getting the value of Username entered in Registration Form, how do I get it so my Log in Form could read it?

Comment: Please add more information regarding what you have tried and what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say you have two JFrames, `Frame1` and `Frame2`. I not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I'm going to assume that `Frame1` launches `Frame2`. If not, you can just do this from the main() method. If you're trying to do it even another way, the concept stays the same.

All you really have to do, give Frame1 an instance of Frame2 so that Frame1 can manipulate it and give (change) some of the data inside Frame2.

You'll need to create an instance of Frame2 so you change data inside it.

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame{

Frame2 frame2;

    public Frame1(){
    frame2 = new Frame2();
    frame2.setVisible(true);
    // Set the rest of the frame up here
    }

}
```

Inside Frame2, you'll need a method that takes the parameters of whatever String you want to pass into it (in this case, the String you want from the JTextField).

```
public class Frame2 extends JFrame{

    String fieldText;

    public void setFieldData(String fieldText){
        this.fieldText = fieldText;
    }

}
```

Now you're all set to set the a String from one frame, and pass it into the other.

Also, this code was written off the cuff, so there might be a typo or two :)